# Selecting specific rows based on values in 2 columns in R

Tags: database, r, count, plyr

I have a large data set of GPS collar locations that have a varying number of locations each day. I want to separate out only the days that have a single location collected and make a new data frame containing all their information.

```
month    day    easting    northing    time    ID
  6       1     #######    ########    0:00    ##
  6       2     #######    ########    6:00    ##
  6       2     #######    ########    0:00    ##
  6       3     #######    ########    18:00   ##
  6       3     #######    ########    12:00   ##
  6       4     #######    ########    0:00    ##
  6       5     #######    ########    6:00    ##
```

Currently I have hashed together something, but can't quite get to the next step.

```
library(plyr)
dog<-count(data1,vars=c("MONTH","day"))
datasub1<-subset(dog,freq==1)
```

This gives me a readout that looks like

```
    MONTH day freq
1       6  29    1
7       7   5    1
8       7   6    1
10      7   8    1
12      7  10    1
```

I am trying to use the values of the Month and day to pull out the rows that contain them from the main dataset so that I can make a data frame containing only the points with a frequency of 1 but that contains all the associated data. I've got to this point:

```
sis<-c(datasub1$MONTH)
bro<-c(datasub1$day)
datasub2<-subset(data1,MONTH==sis&day==bro)
```

... but that doesn't give me anything, personally it makes intuitive sense (R beginner) that it should subset out the rows that contain both the values of bro and sis.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised:

```
datasub2<-subset(data1, paste(month,day,sep=".") %in% paste(datasub1$MONTH, datasub1$day,sep=".") )
```

It's not very likely (and quite possibly impossible) that any particular MONTH item will exactly equal that subset. You are presumably more interested in whether a combo of "Month.Day" is  in the combo sets of "Month.Day" in the datasub1. You have mixed up the capitalization that returns from the count() function if the headers were as you illustrated.

```
> dog
  month day freq
1     6   1    1
2     6   2    2
3     6   3    2
4     6   4    1
5     6   5    1
> datasub1
  month day freq
1     6   1    1
4     6   4    1
5     6   5    1
> datasub2
  month day easting northing time ID
1     6   1 ####### ######## 0:00 ##
6     6   4 ####### ######## 0:00 ##
7     6   5 ####### ######## 6:00 ##
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with %n% and for some reason when I search it in google and on here it only recognizes is a a regular n, even with quotes. This code returns the entire data set back to me. I was doing the bro and sis code because the databases are separated out by year, so if the frequency of location fixes on a specific day is 1, then there is only a single occurrence of that combination of month and day within the dataset.

Comment: First point, it's `%in%` not `%n%`. See `help(match)`. Second point, you are expecting us to read your mind (so far unsuccessfully) for what is in "sis" and "bro". No one has apparently intuited what your goal is.

Comment: Sorry, I'll check it out in the help section.

Comment: In the original post, after dog<-count(data1,vars=c("MONTH","day")), I subsetted out all those that had a frequency of 1. So I was left with a dataframe that looked like the second readout in the original post, only 3 columns, MONTH, day, and freq. Sis is the values of MONTH and bro is the values of day from that reduced dataframe. So I was hoping to be able to subset the original larger dataset using the corresponding values of sis and bro as they co-occur in a row only once, and remove those rows.

Comment: So, for example, I on the 6th of the 6th month there was a frequency of 1 for location fixes. For the next 3 days there are a varying number of location fixes so I don't want to touch them, and on the 10th there is a single frequency again. Sis would be 6,6 and bro would be 6,10. So I was hoping to be able to subset out the data saying that when sis is 6 and bro is 6, remove that row, and then when sis is 6 and bro is 10, remove that row. And so on. I hope that makes sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think I finally figure out what you wanted. You just want the cases where the "month" and "day" variables were associated with a "freq" of 1.

Comment: Ah, perfect, that's done it. Now to study what you did so I can understand all the component parts. Sorry about all the confusion and thanks for sticking it out with me.

Comment: We needed to create a way to represent a pairing of conditions that applied equally to both the bigger set and the selected set. I can think of other ways of doing it with 'ave' and perhaps with plyr using the 'summarise' mode.

Answer (score 0):

After this:

```
library(plyr)
dog<-count(data1,vars=c("MONTH","day"))
```

try this:

```
indx = which(dog$freq==1)
data1[indx,]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I use the count code it collapses the data set, those days that have more than 1 location point are placed in a single row. So the data set goes from 509 rows to 149, and when I do the above code it gives me the data for the lines corresponding to the 149 rows. If that makes sense. So, when instead of selecting out day 7, which has a single location point but falls on row 25, it selects row 7 instead (each day collapses to a single row). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
data1[rownames(datasub1), ]
```

This is an extension of the OP's original thinking but may not be what they're after and is really just what Wesley suggested but carrying the OP's original steps one more forward (minus the bro sis part which confused me a bit because...well for the same reason DWin said :)).  You're after the rownames not really the values in those columns.  You've already got that information.  The row names carry that information back to the original data set.

```
n <- 100
data1 <- data.frame(
    Accuracy = round(runif(n, 0, 5), 1),
    MONTH    = sample(1:5, n, replace=TRUE),
    day      = sample(1:28, n, replace=TRUE),
    Easting  = rnorm(n),
    Northing = rnorm(n),
    Etc      = rnorm(n)
)


library(plyr)
dog<-count(data1,vars=c("MONTH","day"))
datasub1<-subset(dog,freq==1)

data1[rownames(datasub1), ]
```

Comment: The same thing happened with this code as that provided by Wesley above. Unfortunately, when I use the count code it collapses the data set, those days that have more than 1 location point are placed in a single row. So the data set goes from 509 rows to 149, and when I do the above code it gives me the data for the lines corresponding to the 149 rows. If that makes sense. So, when instead of selecting out day 7, which has a single location point but falls on row 25, it selects row 7 instead (each day collapses to a single row). Does that make sense?