# Subset a data frame with multiple match conditions in R

Tags: r, match, subset

With the sample data

```
> df1 <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,3), y=c("a","b","a","b"))
> df1
  x y
1 1 a
2 1 b
3 2 a
4 3 b
> df2 <- data.frame(x=c(1,3), y=c("a","b"))
> df2
  x y
1 1 a
2 3 b
```

I want to remove all the value pairs (x,y) of df2 from df1. I can do it using a for loop over each row in df2 but I'm sure there is a better and simpler way that I just can't think of at the moment. I've been trying to do something starting with the following:

```
> df1$x %in% df2$x & df1$y %in% df2$y
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

But this isn't what I want as df1[2,] = (1,b) is pulled out for removal. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: I just answered an identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932781/selecting-specific-rows-based-on-values-in-2-columns-in-r/8932951#8932951

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build a set of pairs from df2:

```
prs <- with(df2, paste(x,y,sep="."))
```

Test each row in df1 with similarly process for membership in the pairset:

```
df1[ paste(df1$x, df1$y, sep=".") %in% prs , ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much DWin. I had checked out the thread you responded in before when I was researching this issue, but was confused by the question asked and didn't realize I could apply it to my problem. My apologies and thanks again!

Comment: I understand. As you can tell from the comments, I was confused as well. Your question was clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You could go the other way around: `rbind` everything and remove duplicates

```
out <-rbind(df1,df2)
out[!duplicated(out, fromLast=TRUE) & !duplicated(out),]

  x y
2 1 b
3 2 a
```

Comment: That is another solution and it works fine for the sample data here. For my real data however it won't work as the equivalent to df1 has multiple duplicate rows. Thanks though!